# How to compare information from a file in python

Tags: python, user-input

So I have a file and I want to compare it with my user's input so that the file's information may equal what the user has inputted. In the reg_login.txt it holds information.

```
 Username = Emmanuel, Password = emman
 Username = Emmanuel, Password = em
```

I want the code to compare the user's input and the reg_login.txt and make sure that what it says in the text file is equal with the program. If it doesn't equal then ask the user to input again and again until the reg_login.txt is equal with the user's input

When I write the code

```
username1 = input("What is your username?: ")

password2 = input("What is your password!")

reg = open("reg_login.txt")

if username1 = "Username =" = open("reg_login.txt")

if password2 = "Password =" = open("reg_login.txt")
```

I expected the program to compare the strings and variables.

Comment: Where did you learn that `if username1 = "Username =" = open("reg_login.txt")` would compare the value of `username1` to whatever is in the file?

Comment: Your `if` statements don't do what you think they do. Are you trying to read the content of that file?

Comment: An alternate option is to choose a file format that already has a well known parser. JSON comes to mind. You'll need to more fully describe that file format (can the fields be in a different order, is the password encrypted, what if the password contains an '=' or ',', ? etc...) if you want to roll your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> compare the strings and variables

`open()` alone does not read the file. You will need to iterate over the lines.

For example,

```
match = False
while not match:
  user = input("What is your username?: ")
  password = input("What is your password!")

  with open("reg_login.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
      if line.startswith(f'Username = {user},') and line.rstrip().endswith(f'Password = {password}'):
        print('Matching user!')
        match = True
        break

print(f'Hello {user}.')
```

Keep in mind - passwords should never be stored or entered as easily readable plaintext values.

Comment: Make sure there's a `,` after the username. Otherwise the username `foo` will match `Username = foobar`